# facebook like box not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get facebook like box working on mobile . 
i used the code generated by : Like Button Configurator
on this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button 
the snippet is working just fine on the browser. 
On the laptop browser the plugin request `https://web.facebook.com/login.php` then when you login it reload the page and you can like . 
but on the mobile version `https://m.facebook.com/login.php` is requested and the request is not performed well so the page doesn't get loaded even after the user login and when I click like nothing heppens but it work once I reload the page manually.

here is the error displayed on the mobile console :

> m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.co…small%26_rdc%3D1%26ret%3Doptin%26act%3Dconnect%26hash%3DAQB_JyCEathOyJFc:1 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.facebook.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://web.facebook.com').(anonymous function) @ m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.co…small%26_rdc%3D1%26ret%3Doptin%26act%3Dconnect%26hash%3DAQB_JyCEathOyJFc:1

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure that all fb files are loaded on mobile view
- Possible case is that you didn't add the http//: prefix.* Potentially worth checking.
- If there is a generated iframe on mobile, keep in mind that mobile old browsers does not support or have poor suppport for iframe.

Comment: yes they are loaded and there is no error . dont understand the prefix point ? here is my code live : sellpizzasonline.com

Comment: Is there an ifram generated for the like button?

Comment: yes the SDK js insert an iframe for the like button

Comment: Old mobile browsers does not support or have poor suppport for iframe.

Comment: I've tested the code on the last version of chrome on Android and IOS and still have the same error when I login ..it works perfectly if i'm already logged in facebook before visiting the page . but if not it asks me to login then when i login nothing happens when i click like and it throws this error on the console http://imgur.com/a/kYkHo

Comment: After login, if you refreshed the page, every thing works well?

Comment: I seems like a bug.. some changes should take place but they don't.. As a workaround you can trigger login and call reload()